Constructing a primitive element for each fixed field of a Galois extension
Let $K/F$ be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$ and normal basis $ \{\sigma(\alpha):\sigma\in G\} $ and let $H\leq G$ be a subgroup. I am asked to show that that $F(Tr_{K/K^H}(\alpha))=K^H$.
Setting $Tr_{K/K^H}(\alpha)=\alpha_H$, my guess was to show that $[F(\alpha_H):F]\geq [G:H]$. And then to do so, I took a set of representatives $X$ for the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ and considered the polynomial $\prod_{\sigma\in X}(t-\sigma(x_H))$ and my goal was to show that it is irreducible over $F$. The first order of business was to show that it is a polynomial over $F$. Now if $q\in G$, then $q\sigma=\tilde{\sigma}\eta$ for some $\tilde{\sigma}\in X$ and $\eta\in H$, which means that $q\sigma(\alpha_H)=\tilde{\sigma}(\alpha_H)$. This means that $f\in F[t]$, but here I got stuck showing that it is irreducible. Am I on the right track or is there a better way to solve this problem?

The key point is that $\alpha$ is the generator of a normal basis. Let $\tau \in G$. Because  $\alpha_H=\sum_{\sigma\in H}\sigma(\alpha)$, $\tau(\alpha_H)=\alpha_H$ iff $\tau \in H$. Therefore using the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory you obtain $deg(\alpha_H|F)=[G:H]$, as required.

Can you check if my answer makes sense?

Your answer is essentially correct.
Shorter and slightly clearer argument for your $4^{th}$ paragraph, second to third but last sentences: "If we had $\tau \notin H$, then $\tau(\alpha_H)=\sum_{\sigma \in H}\sigma\tau(\alpha) \not= \sum_{\sigma \in H}\sigma(\alpha) = \alpha_H$ because of the linear independency of ${\sigma(\alpha):\sigma \in G}$".

I think I have an answer. Let $G=Gal(K/F)$
Since $N=\{\sigma(\alpha):\sigma\in G\}$ is a normal basis, then $|N|=[K:F]=|G|$ since $K/F$ is Galois. Consider now the map $G\rightarrow N,\sigma\mapsto\sigma(\alpha)$ and note that it is a surjection, and, therefore, a bijection. Suppose that $\sigma\in Gal(K/F(\alpha))$. Then $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha=id(\alpha)$, which means that $\sigma=id$. Hence, $Gal(K/F(\alpha))$ is the trivial subgroup which means that $K=F(\alpha)$
Now, to show that $F(\alpha_H)=K^H$, it suffices to show that their Galois groups are equal. So we aim to show that $Gal(K/F(\alpha_H))=Gal(K/K^H)$. Since $F(\alpha_H)\subseteq K^H$, then $Gal(K/K^H)\subseteq Gal(K/F(\alpha_H))$.
Suppose now that that $\tau\in Gal(K/F(\alpha_H))$. It follows that $\tau(\alpha_H)=\alpha_H$. Hence, $\sum_{\sigma\in H}\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha_H=\sum_{\sigma\in H}\tau\sigma(\alpha)$. Now if $\tau\sigma(\alpha)=\tilde{\sigma}(\alpha)$ for some $\sigma,\tilde{\sigma}\in H$, then by the first part, $\tau\sigma=\tilde{\sigma}$  which means that $\tau\in H$. Otherwise, for no $\sigma,\tilde{\sigma}\in H$ is $\tau\sigma(\alpha)=\tilde{\sigma}(\alpha)$. But then $\sum_{\sigma\in H}\sigma(\alpha)+\sum_{\beta\in H}-\tau\beta(\alpha)=0$, which contradicts the linear independency of $\{\eta(\alpha):\eta\in G\}$. Hence $\tau\in H$. Thus, $Gal(K/F(\alpha_H))\subseteq H=Gal(K/K^H)$.
